# In splunk Dashboard How to hide/unhide input radio choice options based on previous input?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

In splunk dashboard(Classic) I want to hide/hide the input radio option choice based on previous input radio button selection.

```
<form>
  <label>tst2</label>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" token="environment">
    <label>ENV</label>
    <choice value="US">USA</choice>
    <choice value="Asia">APAC</choice>
    <choice value="UAE">UAE</choice>
    </input>
    <input type="radio" token="sub-environment1">
    <label>S-ENV</label>
    <choice value="*">All</choice>
    <choice value="NewYork">NY</choice>
    <choice value="LA">LA</choice>
    <choice value="Washington">WT</choice>
    <choice value="Delhi">DL</choice>
    <choice value="Mumbai">MB</choice>
    <choice value="Tokio">TK</choice>
    <choice value="Dubai">DB</choice>
    <choice value="Abu-Dabhi">ABD</choice>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

In this case

if i select USA then it should display - NY,LA,WT and * . Rest all other sub-environment  should hide.

if i select APAC it should display radio inputs as DL, MB,TK and * . Rest all other sub-environment  should hide.

if i select UAE it should display DB, ABD and * . Rest all other sub-environment  should hide.

Is there any why we can use tokens or depends or any other approach to hide/unhide these second(sub-environment) radio input choices

Answer (score 0):

The `depends="$token$"` format works on *almost* every XML element in Splunk Dashboards

I do this to force choices to happen in a certain order

For example, if you must choose a Region before a Datacenter, you might have the dropdown for Datacenter have `depends="$regiontok$"`, so that Region has to be set first